# How to add “data-validation” attribute to mvc 5 razor view text input editor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-web-api

Trying to add “data-validation” attribute to mvc 5 razor view text input editor.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

want to add:
data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min3" data-validation-error-msg="3 char"

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: `new { @class = "form-control", new data_validation = "length", data_validation_length = "min3", etc }` (note the underscore character)

Answer (score 4):

For `data` attributes in razor, instead of using attribute value `data-validation` directly, you should change it to `data_validation`:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", data_validation="length", data_validation_length="min3", data_validation_error_msg="3 char" } })
```

In short - for attributes `_` in C# code are changed to `-` in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Do it the same as you add the `class` attribute, but replace with `_` instead of `-`.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" @data_validation="length" @data_validation_length="min3" @data_validation_error_msg="3 char" } })
```